# Find the parent ID for every component which has an ID attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, components, tree-traversal

I am using JDK1.7, JSF2 and Primefaces.

I have a `.xhtml` as below. I want to list the `Parent and the Child Relations` as following `<Component Id Tree Structure> | <Id> | <Child of Id- Parent>` as shown in the `Expected Output`

**xhtml :**

```
<h:form id="rootParentForm">

    <p:treeTable id="singleTreeTble" value="#{ttSelectionView.root1}" var="document" selectionMode="single" selection="#{ttSelectionView.selectedNode}" style="margin-top:0">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Single
        </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{document.name}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Size">
            <h:outputText value="#{document.size}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Type">
            <h:outputText value="#{document.type}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:treeTable>

    <p:commandButton id="singleCmdBtn" value="Display" update="msgs" icon="ui-icon-newwin"
                        actionListener="#{ttSelectionView.displaySelectedSingle}"/>


    <h3 style="margin-top:0">Basic</h3>
    <p:accordionPanel id="basicAP">
        <p:tab id="basicTab1" title="Godfather Part I">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather1.jpg" />
                <h:outputText
                    value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone..." />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="basicTab2" title="Godfather Part II">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather2.jpg" />
                <h:outputText value="Francis Ford Coppola's legendary..." />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="basicTab3" title="Godfather Part III">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />
                <h:outputText value="After a break of more than 15 years..." />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>

    <h3>Multiple Selection</h3>
    <p:accordionPanel id="multipleAP" multiple="true">
        <p:tab id="multipleTab1"  title="Godfather Part I">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather1.jpg" />
                <h:outputText
                    value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone..." />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="multipleTab2"  title="Godfather Part II">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather2.jpg" />
                <h:outputText value="Francis Ford Coppola's legendary..." />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="multipleTab3"  title="Godfather Part III">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />
                <h:outputText value="After a break of more than 15 years...." />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>    
</h:form>
```

**Expected Output:** 
[image: Expected Output]

What is the best approach to do this? So, that all the parent and child relations will be listed as expected.

I will upload the xhtml page and then i want to find & show the parent-child relation.

Comment: What do you mean with these words: "I will upload the xhtml page and then i want to find & show the parent-child relation"? Do you want to build and analyze component tree after uploading some Facelets file without redeloying an app? Should this uploaded xhtml be relevant to running application or just any "spherical Facelets file in vacuum"?

Comment: @iTollu I mean to have a FileUpload Page as it is in [ShowCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml), and once uploaded Successfully i want to show the parent-child relation into a file

Comment: Then you can either consider uploaded file as part of existing context (against which all expressions would be resolved) or as completely independent code. Which one is true in your case?

Comment: @iTollu In my case uploaded file is a part of existing context.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you should:

1. Get current FacesContext with `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()`;
2. Get view root with current instance's `getViewRoot()` -- you will
   get instance of `UIComponent`, which has `visitTree()` method;
3. Use `UIComponent` instance's `visitTree()` method -- pass it callback
   function which tests, whether id attribute was set etc.

You may find JSF API Documentation bundled with [JSF Specifications](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr344/index.html) useful.

To perform it all, You will need to parse xhtml into component tree. If it is Facelets markup, classes from  `javax.faces.view.facelets` package will be useful as well as `javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper`.

If uploaded xhtml is irrelevant to your server-side application, you will also need to stub EL expressions.